# laravel eloquent get all relationship data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following setup in Laravel - a client who can have many reports which contains many rows of data

Client Object (can have many reports)

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function reports()
    {
      return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Report')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Report Object (can have many rows of data)

```
class Report extends Model
{
    public function data()
    {
      return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Data', 'report_data')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Data Object (belongs to a report)

```
class Data extends Model
{

    public function report()
    {
      return $this
        ->belongsTo('App\Report')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

If i want to fetch a report for a client i can do this (if i wanted to grab the first one):

```
$report = $client -> reports -> first();
var_dump($report -> data); die;
```

That would give me all the data for the first report

Or:

```
foreach($client -> reports as $report){
     var_dump($report -> data);
}
```

Now the question is - if a client had 3 reports how could i get all the data combined for those 3 reports?

So for example if a client had 3 reports like:

```
Report 1
Name: test
View: 100
Revenue: 10

Report 2
Name: foo
Views: 50
Revenue: 30

Report 3
Name: bah
Views: 40
Revenue: 20
```

We could get:

```
Name: Total
Views: 190
Revenue: 60
```

I have tried looping over the reports and merging them into one collection but it doesn't work

```
  $reports = $client -> reports -> all();

  $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

  foreach($reports as $report){

      $collection = $collection -> merge($report -> data);
  }

  var_dump($collection);
  die;
```

The relationship has got me a little stumped

Comment: "I have tried looping over the reports and merging them into one collection but it doesn't work". Please update your post with this code that you have tried.

Comment: Updated to add the colletion loop

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, you can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to get the model with related data. If you already have the model and want it's related data, you can use Lazy Loading

```
$client->load('reports.data');
```

After that you can check the content with

```
dd($client);
```

For getting the total of views, you can do

```
$totalViews = $client->reports->sum('views');
```

Since you will be working with [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

And you will see the `relations` field populated with all the reports and, inside them, all the data results for each one.

EDIT

If you want all the data in one place, you can use

```
$allData = $client->reports->pluck('data');
```

Also, have in mind that maybe Laravel hav the attribute `data` reserved in the models, so if you continue having troubles, try changing that relation name for something like `reportData` and the model `ReportData`.

Comment: I can get all the reports with their relevant data results - but i need the merged into one report - and all the data values summed

Comment: You shouldn't do that, because a Model represents a Database Record. I'll edit my answer to add a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$reports = [];
foreach($client -> reports as $report){
     $reports [] = $report->data;
}
var_dump($reports);
```

Comment: I need the result to be an eloquent Report model - with the data being the 3 reports data combined

Comment: each report has many datas ryt ?? so tou need all report's data as one array ??

Comment: I need all the reports data to be summed into one

Comment: `Name: test` is this report name ? `Views: 40` is this sum of all datas for one report ??